# Can I have multiple, independent CoreData stacks in an application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I originally assumed the answer to my question was a simple 'yes', but some of the reading I've done since has had me looking at the question again.

My intention is to use modular code, which lets me pick and choose from a number of code sections to add various features to an app.  As an example, I might have a browser component that allows for safe-browsing, a survey component to take user surveys, and a 'core' component that is the primary purpose of the app -- be it displaying a menu or displaying a map of a location.

I'd want each independent module to have it's own CoreData stack.  They don't talk to each other or interfere with each other in any way, outside of whatever is mediated by the app itself (communication to the app done using the delegate model).  The browser's list of bookmarks and whitelisted sites is separate from the survey's list of survey data, which is also completely seperate from anything the 'core' of the app does.  If they need to talk to each other, they can do so through delegate calls, which will consist of telling the app 'I need a browser to display X page', 'display the survey with this id', or finally "I'm done, return to the main app".

What started me down this path was realizing that there was no way to determine whether a given NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification belongs to a given core data stack or not.  And, presumably, giving a MOC the notification from a different core data stack in the  mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification: method would be a bad idea.  (I'm also concerned what happens when you try to feed a MOC's own notification back into it, but that's something I can experiment with easily enough)

Answer (score 5):

You can (and this is explicitly recommended in the NSManagedObjectContext documentation)
register for changes coming from a specific context:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                           selector:@selector(<#Selector name#>)
                               name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                             object:<#A managed object context#>];
```

and when you receive such a notification, the notification object is the managed object context. It is therefore possible to create independent components where each
component uses its own Core Data stack.

Answer (score 1):

As Martin R noted, you can register for notifications from a specific context. If you're listening for notifications from more than one context, it's also possible to ask the notification which context posted it and proceed based on that. With `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`, look at `[notification object]` to find out which context posted it.

Keeping your objects in entirely different stacks, with separate persistent stores, seems excessive unless there's some kind of security-related issue. Like maybe, for some reason it's very important that one collection of data never be allowed to near some other collection. As described, the app doesn't seem to have any compelling reason for the extra complexity.

You might find it preferable to use one stack and one persistent store, but with multiple configurations. Each configuration would include specific entities from the data model. You'd have a single persistent store and one `NSManagedObjectModel` instance but multiple `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` instances. Indicate which configuration you want when calling `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:`.

Comment: The purpose for separate stacks is just to avoid extra work by trying to hand-merge the models for each application -- it also allows me to update the models of the modules with relative ease, as I can change them in one place and let the git Submodules handle pulling in the changes.  I'll have to read up on doing it via configurations.